# Can add file but cannot set metadata in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I can copy file to Google Cloud Storage:

```
% gsutil -m cp audio/index.csv gs://passive-english/audio/
If you experience problems with multiprocessing on MacOS, they might be related to https://bugs.python.org/issue33725. You can disable multiprocessing by editing your .boto config or by adding the following flag to your command: `-o "GSUtil:parallel_process_count=1"`. Note that multithreading is still available even if you disable multiprocessing.

Copying file://audio/index.csv [Content-Type=text/csv]...
\ [1/1 files][196.2 KiB/196.2 KiB] 100% Done
Operation completed over 1 objects/196.2 KiB.
```

But I can't change it metadata:

```
% gsutil setmeta -h "Cache-Control:public, max-age=7200" gs://passive-english/audio/index.csv
Setting metadata on gs://passive-english/audio/index.csv...
AccessDeniedException: 403 Access denied.
```

I'm authorizing using json file:

```
% env | grep GOOGL
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/app-342xxx-2cxxxxxx.json
```

How can I grant access so that gsutil can change metadata for the file?

**Update 1:**

I give the service account role Editor and `Storage Object Admin` permission.

**Update 2**:
I give the service account role Owner and Storage Object Admin permission. Still no use

[image]

Comment: What roles does your service account have?

Answer (score 1):

To update an object's metadata you need the IAM permission `storage.objects.update`.

That permission is contained in the roles:

- `Storage Object Admin (roles/storage.objectAdmin)
- `Storage Admin (roles/storage.admin)

To add the required role using the CLI:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${GCP_PROJECT_ID} \
    --member=serviceAccount:${GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL}
    --role=REPLACE_WITH_REQUIRED_ROLE (e.g. roles/storage.objectAdmin)
```

Using the Google Cloud Console GUI:

- In the Cloud Console, go to the IAM & Admin -> IAM page.
- Locate the service account.
- Click the pencil icon on the right hand side.
- Click ADD ROLE.
- Select one of the required roles.

Comment: I did. It still return AccessDeniedException. Is it instant? Or I have to wait?

Comment: I updated my question to include the roles of the service account

Comment: @PhươngNguyễn can take a couple of minutes, but not a long time. Do you have "fine-grained" or "Uniform" access control enabled on the bucket?

Comment: I have waited 4 hours, the result is the same. I use bucket level access control.

Comment: Use this command and then retry: `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/path/to/service-account.json`

Comment: I don't have gcloud. I installed gsutil with `pip3 install gsutil`. I installed `gcloud` with `pip3 install gcloud` but it doesn't yield `gcloud` command in the terminal.

Comment: what is activate-service-account do? my gsutil already correctly load the key file, because it can copy the file to the bucket.

Comment: Sets the service account that gcloud and gsutil will use. The issue with permission denied after adding the correct IAM roles indicates that gsutil is not using the identity that you think it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249578/discussion-between-phng-nguyn-and-john-hanley).

Comment: You are right. As soon as I use `gsutil config -e` to specify the key file, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to update metadata,  I can able to successfully edit without errors.

According to [documention](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/patch) , you need to have `Owner` role on the object to edit meatadata.

you can also refer this document [1](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-gsutil) & [2](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata)

Comment: What does it mean? I have change the service account role to Owner, still getting access denied.

Comment: Please clarify your answer by specifying the actual role names instead of the term `Owner` as that will mislead future readers. In my answer I specified the required permission and two of the roles that posses that permission.

Comment: @Phương Nguyễn can you able to edit in console, have you tried? https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/viewing-editing-metadata#console

Comment: Yes I can. Through the console it works.